# A conformal image of a Brownian motion is a time changed Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, conformal-geometry

I have read a paper which has stated the following:

> A conformal image of a Brownian motion is a time changed Brownian motion.

The paper cites *R. Durret, Brownian motion and martingales in analysis, Wadsworth Advanced Books & Software, 1984*. However, I don't have access to that book, so I was trying to figure it out myself. As I have minor understanding of conformal maps, I am left clueless with this problem. Hints?

Comment: Did you actually try google on this topic? There are lots of sources in https://www.google.com/search?q=conformal+mapping+Brownian+motion